# how to fix wordpress cpu run 100%++ every time

Tags: wordpress, memory, cpu-usage

I try disable all plugin or tye optimization database and try install new vps but still cpu 100%

how to fix solve ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to increase the memory limit in the wp-config.php file, https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/fix-wordpress-memory-exhausted-error-increase-php-memory/

I recommend no less than 750M

It's possible there are other PHP variables like the max_execution_time and max_input_time that might also need increasing, but start with the memory limit and see if that helps.